# Desbordamiento de array

Tags: java, array, hilos

Tengo este problema de desbordamiento en un array que tengo dentro de varios objetos.

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
>       at Ejercicio.Visitante.run(Visitante.java:73)

El código

public class Visitante extends Thread {

```
private String salaReg[];
private String salaRegAnt[];
private Semaphore sem;
private String id;
private Room sala[];

public Visitante(String id, Room sala[], Semaphore sem) {
    this.id = id;
    this.sala = sala;
    this.sem = sem;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    boolean listo = true;
    boolean existe = true;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int numRan;

    try {

        sem.acquire();
        System.out.println("/////////////////HILO " + id);
        System.out.println("Estoy en sala " + sala[0].getId());
        salaReg = sala[0].getReg();
        System.out.println("Actual");
        for (int m = 0; m < salaReg.length; m++) {
            System.out.printf(salaReg[m] + " | ");
        }

        while (listo) {
            if (salaReg[j].equals(" ")) {
                salaReg[j] = id;
                sala[0].setReg(salaReg);
                listo = false;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }
        j = 0;
        listo = true;
        numRan = (int) (Math.random() * 2000 + 400);
        Thread.sleep(numRan);

        System.out.println("Museo con " + sala.length + " salas");
        for (int i = 1; i < sala.length; i++) {
            salaReg = null;
            System.out.println("Soy " + id + "  y estoy en sala " + sala[i].getId());

            salaReg = sala[i].getReg();//Array que se supone que debería estar vacio
            //ya que a cada sala del array de salas
            //se le ha "seteado" un array de tipo String
            //con tamaño 7
            //e inicializada a " "

            salaRegAnt = sala[i - 1].getReg();//este array del anterior objeto(por eso i-1)
            //debería tener 1 sólo dato

            System.out.println("Actual");
            for (int m = 0; m < salaReg.length; m++) {
                System.out.printf(salaReg[m] + " | ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            while (listo) {
                if (salaReg[j].equals(" ")) {
                    salaReg[j] = id;
                    sala[i].setReg(salaReg);
                    System.out.println("Antes");
                    for (int m = 0; m < salaRegAnt.length; m++) {
                        System.out.printf(salaRegAnt[m] + " | ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();

                    while (existe) {
                        if (salaRegAnt[k].equals(id)) {
                            salaRegAnt[k] = " ";
                            sala[i - 1].setReg(salaRegAnt);
                            System.out.println("Despues");
                            for (int m = 0; m < salaRegAnt.length; m++) {
                                System.out.printf(salaRegAnt[m] + " | ");
                            }
                            System.out.println();
                            existe = false;
                        } else {
                            k++;
                        }
                    }

                    listo = false;

                } else {
                    j++;
                }
            }
            j = 0;
            k = 0;
            listo = true;
            numRan = (int) (Math.random() * 2000 + 800);
            Thread.sleep(numRan);
        }
        sem.release();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Aclaro que en una clase principal he creado un array de String, y ese array de String la asigné a un array de objetos.

Espero recibir alguna aclaración, ya que no logro encontrar el fallo.

Comment: revisa esta parte `for (int m = 0; m < salaRegAnt.length; m++) {
                                    System.out.printf(salaRegAnt[m] + " | ");
                                }`se esta saliendo del limite de tu array salaRegAnt

Comment: eso es sólo como prueba para poder ver el array del objeto anterior, ya que lo que pretendo es ir de objeto en objeto insertando un numero (id) al objeto actual y quitado del objeto anterior. :/

Comment: pero tu fallo dice en la linea 75 desbordamiento de array

Comment: Sí, pero lo he editado y quité algunas lineas que tenía comentada y tal para que no haya muchas lineas. ahora corrijo

Comment: El problema me da en la linea siguiente:
 if (salaReg[j].equals(" ")) {

al parecer nunca encuentra en el array el " " y el contador por ello va avanzando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

revisa la linea 73

haciendo cambios a la line 73 tenemos que delimitar los indices de array
**modificando:**

```
if ((salaReg[j].equals(" ")) ) {
```

por:

```
if ((j<salaReg.length)&&(salaReg[j].equals(" ")) ) {
```

ya no se ocurre el error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7 at
>   Ejercicio.Visitante.run(Visitante.java:73)